# Storing IPv4 and IPv6 hosts and networks

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes, network

I have to store the IPv4/v6 address **and networks**(CIDR notation) in a MySQL database. Unfortunately, I am constrained to use Mysql.

So, I'm looking for the equivalent of the [`inet` type of  PostgreSql.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html) :

> **The inet type holds an IPv4 or IPv6 host address, and optionally its
>   subnet, all in one field**. The subnet is represented by the number of
>   network address bits present in the host address (the "netmask"). If
>   the netmask is 32 and the address is IPv4, then the value does not
>   indicate a subnet, only a single host. In IPv6, the address length is
>   128 bits, so 128 bits specify a unique host address.
>
> The input format for this type is address/y where address is an IPv4
>   or IPv6 address and y is the number of bits in the netmask. If the /y
>   portion is missing, the netmask is 32 for IPv4 and 128 for IPv6, so
>   the value represents just a single host. On display, the /y portion is
>   suppressed if the netmask specifies a single host.

I'm aware of the followings functions of Mysql 5.6 [INET_ATON(), INET_NTOA(), INET6_ATON(), INET6_NTOA()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton). But I use Mysql 5.5... [So, forget INET6_xxxx](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton).

I'm also aware of the following question "[Storing IP address](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/storing-ip-address)" but it doesn't deals with network CIDR notation.

How you would implement the equivalent of `inet` type in Mysql 5.5?

- 3 columns : Network (2xBIGINT), CIDR (TINYINT) ?
- string ? (@Phil)

Comment: Do you need to do any kind of calculations with the addresses within the database? If not, just store them as strings. What sort of querying will you be doing on the addresses themselves?

Comment: I need to check if a list of IPs is in one of the network. So, the answer is yes. I can also retrieve all  rows and to calculation out of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

First: there is no equivalent of the `inet` type of PostgreSql in MySQL yet.

You should just use the `string` type to store all kind of IP addresses.
if you need them all in a certain format, convert them before inserting them into the DB.

If you need to do calculations with them, as you mentioned `INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()` are the needed functions to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Building on rubo77...  if the address block is stored in CIDR notation, then it might be desirable to determine the first and last ip address of the block.

assuming our CIDR block is '10.20.30.40/24'

```
mysql test> set @cidr:='10.20.30.40/24';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql test> select @cidr;
+----------------+
| @cidr          |
+----------------+
| 10.20.30.40/24 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

99% of the time, the address in the cidr notation is the first address of the address block.  Sometimes, people make mistakes (as I have intentionally done here), so we can find the first address just to be safe by...

```
select inet_ntoa( (@shifted_network_number :=
                   inet_aton(substring_index(@cidr,'/',1)) >> (@host_bits:=(32-substring_index(@cidr,'/',-1))))
                                                           << @host_bits) as starting_ip;
+-------------+
| starting_ip |
+-------------+
| 10.20.30.0  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The ending address...

```
select inet_ntoa( ((@shifted_network_number :=
                 inet_aton(substring_index(@cidr,'/',1)) >> (@host_bits:=(32-substring_index(@cidr,'/',-1)))) + 1
                                                         << @host_bits) - 1) as starting_ip;
+--------------+
| starting_ip  |
+--------------+
| 10.20.30.255 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The address range...

```
select concat( inet_ntoa( (@shifted_network_number :=
                       inet_aton(substring_index(@cidr,'/',1)) >> (@host_bits:=(32-substring_index(@cidr,'/',-1))))
                                                               << @host_bits)
              , ' - '
              , inet_ntoa( (((@shifted_network_number + 1) << @host_bits) - 1))) as IP_Range;
+---------------------------+
| IP_Range                  |
+---------------------------+
| 10.20.30.0 - 10.20.30.255 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```